# JSDoc Tutorial Include Source File

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

I have a JavaScript project that's documented using JSDoc3, and I'm working on adding tutorials (written in HTML).  I have example code in my project consisting of a series of scripts that the user can run, and I'm essentially writing tutorials to explain what each example script does.  I'd like to have a blurb of explanatory text at the top of each tutorial, and then include an example script.  I can copy-and-paste example code into a tutorial file and get it formatted correctly, but ideally I'd like to *include* the file so that I don't have to maintain the example code in two separate locations.  How can I accomplish this using JSDoc3?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a pure, *JSDoc-only* solution, but I know, that [Mocha](https://mochajs.org) (testing framework) could generate good enough documentation from test-files, using [doc-reporter](https://mochajs.org/#doc)

#### Workaround 1

Workaround could look like this:

1. convert your samples to the tests for `mocha`
2. run `mocha --reporter=doc` for new test files
3. forward the output from `mocha` to preprocessor to generate styled documentation

With this solution you will get one bonus: **the examples will be tested**.

#### Workaround 1.a

There are other `mocha` reporters: **html**, **markdown**, **json**. We can use **markdown** reporter in the following variation of the first solution:

1. samples => tests
2. run `mocha -r markdown`
3. store the `mocha`'s output to the root of JSDoc tutorials
4. run `jsdoc` (with tutorials generating)

The main difference: utilizing the [tutorial feature](http://usejsdoc.org/about-tutorials.html) of JSDoc